# loop on a dictionary (previous values) python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary associating a probability to a char

```
d = {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.3, 'c': 0.4, 'd':0.1}
```

And I am searching a way to associate to each char the lowest value of his frequency distribution. So every char must be associated to the sum of the previous ones.
I know dictionary are not ordered but it should return something like

```
ddist = {'a': 0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.5, 'd': 0.9}
```

I tried with a loop but I did not find a way to get the previous values...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply iterate over a sorted version of the keys:

```
d = {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.3, 'c': 0.4, 'd':0.1}
ddist = {}
t = 0
for key in sorted(d):
    ddist[key] = t
    t += d[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

As dicts are unordered, so you need to define the key order yourself, or use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the start.

```
>>> def accumulate(seq):
    total = 0
    for item in seq:
        yield total
        total += item
...         
>>> keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] #For your dict, this is sorted(d)
>>> dict(zip(keys, accumulate(d[k] for k in keys)))
{'a': 0, 'c': 0.5, 'b': 0.2, 'd': 0.9}
#or
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(zip(keys, accumulate(d[k] for k in keys)))
OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 0.2), ('c', 0.5), ('d', 0.9)])
```