# Comparison of value items in a dictionary and counting matches

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, counting

Im using Python 2.7.
Im trying to compare the value items in a dictionary.

I have two problems.
First is the iteration of values in a dictionary with a length of 1. I always get an error, because python doesn't iterate integer and a single item as value is an integer for python. 
I have tried to change the item to a string. I have tried to change the whole dictionary to string. In these cases the iteration compares commas and brackets, as well and thats not the purpose. Therefore I duplicated the item. The values in key:1 and key:4 are one and the same item, two times. This solution works, but it changes a little bit the results, naturally.

The second problem is that the counting of matches doesn't work correctly. 
Yes, because of the first problem, but there is another one.
My code compares all value items, with all other value items in the dictionary. Same moduls are not compared. If there is one match in a comparison, there is no problem.
But if a comparison had two matches, the code will outputs the result two times as one match. But I want just one result, with two matches. 
The code includes many comments, so I hope you can unterstand it.

```
    #dicModul is a dictionary with the modulnames(keys of dictionary) and the components of the modul(value of dictionary).
# If a modul consists of one component, it is impossible to iterate the modul, therefore this component is two times in a modul.
# Any ideas how to iterate a single value item in a dictionary?
dicModul = {0:(0,1),1:(1,1), 2:(2,3,4,5,6,1,7,2), 
          3:(8,1),4:(9,9), 5:(10,10,5,11,0,12,13), 6:(10,11,9,7)}
#The list is needed for the iteration and to operate the different modul in the dictionary by following for loops.
ModulList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] 
#Counter is needed for counting same components in different moduls.
Counter = 0
for modKey in ModulList: #For-loop is needed for iteration of keys
    for modKey2 in ModulList: #2nd for-loop of Modulkeys.The components of moduls have to be checked for matches in other moduls.
                              #Therefore a second iteration of the modul list is needed.
        if modKey == modKey2: #Same moduls do not have to be checked.
            print "Skip same Moduls" 
            Counter  = 0     #The modkey2 have to changed by iteration. The counter have to be reset.
        elif modKey != modKey2: #Different moduls have to be checked.
                for modVal in dicModul[modKey]:  #Iteration of components for iterated modul.
                    if modVal in dicModul[modKey2]: #Checking iterated components in different modul
                        Counter = Counter + 1  #If component was in different moduls, counter will add +1
                        print "Modul: "+str(modKey)+" % Modul: "+str(modKey2)+ " Matches= "+str(Counter) 
                        #print function for both moduls and number of same components 
                        Counter =0
```

I think, if the can separte between the previous checked key and checked key at this juncture, the counter will not start at 0, every time.
I tried to solve the problem and search for solutions, but I didn`t found this case.

[loop on a dictionary (previous values) python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133694/loop-on-a-dictionary-previous-values-python)

[How to access previous/next element while for looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323750/how-to-access-previous-next-element-while-for-looping)

[Count items in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623756/count-items-in-dictionary)

I guess the solution have to look like the next code.
I mark my suggestion with #->

```
#dicModul is a dictionary with the modulnames(keys of dictionary) and the components of the modul(value of dictionary).
# If a modul consists of one component, it is impossible to iterate the modul, therefore this component is two times in a modul.
# Any ideas how to iterate a single value item in a dictionary?
dicModul = {0:(0,1),1:(1,1), 2:(2,3,4,5,6,1,7,2), 
          3:(8,1),4:(9,9), 5:(10,10,5,11,0,12,13), 6:(10,11,9,7)}
#The list is needed for the iteration and to operate the different modul in the dictionary by following for loops.
ModulList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] 
#Counter is needed for counting same components in different moduls.
Counter = 0
for modKey in ModulList: #For-loop is needed for iteration of keys
    for modKey2 in ModulList: #2nd for-loop of Modulkeys.The components of moduls have to be checked for matches in other moduls.
                              #Therefore a second iteration of the modul list is needed.
        if modKey == modKey2: #Same moduls do not have to be checked.
            print "Skip same Moduls" 
            Counter  = 0     #The modkey2 have to changed by iteration. The counter have to be reset  
        elif modKey != modKey2: #Different moduls have to be checked.
                for modVal in dicModul[modKey]:  #Iteration of components for iterated modul.
                    if modVal in dicModul[modKey2]: #Checking iterated components in different modul
                #->     if modKey2 == previous modKey2: #Checking if is the previous modul, so counter is not reset.
                #->           Counter = Counter +1 
                #->           print "Modul: "+str(modKey)+" % Modul: "+str(modKey2)+ " Matches= "+str(Counter) 
                #->     else:
                #->        Counter = 1   #Counter is setted 1, because a same component is found in a different modul.
                    elif:
                        Counter = 0
```

This is my expected solution

```
Modul   Modul   Matches
skip same modul     
0   1   1
0   2   1
0   3   1
0   4   0
0   5   1
skip same modul     
1   2   1
1   3   1
1   4   0
1   5   0
skip same modul     
2   3   1
2   4   0
2   5   1
2   6   1
skip same modul     
3   4   0
3   5   0
skip same modul     
4   5   0
4   6   1
skip same modul     
5   6   3
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing your values as tuples as opposed to lists?

Comment: In a sentence, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ Casey: I use tuples, because I need to name my moduls/ values. Tuples are the easiest way to get a value and a key.                                                       @Padraic: I want to achieve a comparison between all modul items. I have a large csv file and I want to analyze all modul values in regard to same items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you take a look at `for` loops, and how they work. [Codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-cxMGf/0/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096) is a great (free) interactive resource. I'm not 100% sure I understand what  you're asking, so I'm mainly going off of your question title. I think I understand what you're trying to do, but if I do, you're making it really difficult on yourself.

**Iterating** a dictionary with a single item:

```
dicty = {'a': 1}    
for key in dicty:
    print key
```

Iterating through values and keys in dictionaries:

```
for key, val in dicty.iteritems():
    print key
    print val
```

which is equivalent to:

```
for key in stuff:
    val = stuff[key]
    print key
    print val
```

Counting (key) matches in two dicts:

```
count = 0
keys_counted = []

dicty_a = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
dicty_b = {'key1': 'val1', 'keyB': 'valB'}
for keyA, valA in dicty_a.iteritems():
    for keyB, valB in dicty_b.iteritems():
        if keyB == keyA and keyA not in keys_counted:
            count += 1
            keys_counted.append(valA)
```

The most common solution to making sure you **don't duplicate a check** is to build a list, check against it, then throw it out at the end. For example:

```
list_printed = []
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        if [x, y] not in list_printed:
            print x, y
            list_printed.append([y,x])
```

outputs:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 3
3 4
4 4
```

`Enumerate()` allows you to **get both the keys and values of items in your dictionary**, or the iteration number and value if you are looping through a list.

With regard to your issue with **iterating over single items**. [Tuples are weird](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), especially with single items. You need the trailing comma or it's not a tuple, it's an int. Honestly, that strikes me as a bug, not a feature, but optimistically, it's probably important for some computer-sciency reason that's way beyond my paygrade. Also, the big thing that distinguishes lists `[]` and tuples `()` is that tuples are immutable. You probably don't need to be using tuples in this case. Having said that, you were getting your error just because, you said, you can't iterate an integer:

```
loopy = (1,)
for x in loopy:
    print x # this will _not_ raise an error

loopy = (1)
for x in loopy:
    print x # this _will_ raise an error

loopy = [1]
for x in loopy:
    print x # this will _not_ raise an error

loopy = 1
for x in loopy:
    print x # this _will_ raise an error
```

**Applying this to what you're trying to do**:

```
dicModul = {0:(0,1),1:(1,1), 2:(2,3,4,5,6,1,7,2), 
          3:(8,1),4:(9,9), 5:(10,10,5,11,0,12,13), 6:(10,11,9,7)}

keys_checked = []

def get_tuple_matches(t1, t2):
    counter = 0
    matched_list = []
    for x in t1:
        for y in t2:
            stuff = [x, y]
            if stuff not in matched_list and x == y:
                counter +=1
                matched_list.append(stuff)
    return counter

for key_outerloop, val_outerloop in dicModul.iteritems():
    for key_innerloop, val_innerloop in dicModul.iteritems():
        if key_outerloop == key_innerloop:
            print "skip..."
        elif [key_innerloop, key_outerloop] not in keys_checked:
            matches = get_tuple_matches(val_outerloop, val_innerloop)
            keys_checked.append([key_outerloop, key_innerloop])
            print "Modul: " + str(key_outerloop) + " | Modul: " + str(key_innerloop) + " | Matches= "+ str(matches)
```

output:

```
skip...
Modul: 0 | Modul: 1 | Matches= 1
Modul: 0 | Modul: 2 | Matches= 1
Modul: 0 | Modul: 3 | Matches= 1
Modul: 0 | Modul: 4 | Matches= 0
Modul: 0 | Modul: 5 | Matches= 1
Modul: 0 | Modul: 6 | Matches= 0
skip...
Modul: 1 | Modul: 2 | Matches= 1
Modul: 1 | Modul: 3 | Matches= 1
Modul: 1 | Modul: 4 | Matches= 0
Modul: 1 | Modul: 5 | Matches= 0
Modul: 1 | Modul: 6 | Matches= 0
skip...
Modul: 2 | Modul: 3 | Matches= 1
Modul: 2 | Modul: 4 | Matches= 0
Modul: 2 | Modul: 5 | Matches= 1
Modul: 2 | Modul: 6 | Matches= 1
skip...
Modul: 3 | Modul: 4 | Matches= 0
Modul: 3 | Modul: 5 | Matches= 0
Modul: 3 | Modul: 6 | Matches= 0
skip...
Modul: 4 | Modul: 5 | Matches= 0
Modul: 4 | Modul: 6 | Matches= 1
skip...
Modul: 5 | Modul: 6 | Matches= 2
skip...
```

[code](https://repl.it/B1rK)

Comment: your solution didn't fix the single value in the tuple problem and your explanation for why looping over tuples with single values isn't allowed doesn't include tuples.

Comment: There is no problem with single values in tuples. OP was trying to loop using an integer as a value.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear. I assumed OP's problem was trying to loop over something like this: `tup=(1)` thinking he was making a tuple of length one and then trying to loop over it like you would a list of length one. It's hard to know where OP's confusion came from because we don't see what he was doing before he started doing the wonky "duplicate the value" shtick.

Comment: Also I think 5 vs. 6 should be 3 matches: two 10s and an 11

Comment: Pardon my lack of programming skills. Im a newbie and Im trying to solve a problem in economics. Thank you NotAnAmbiTurner for your solution, your idea with a additional list is great.  Im using tuples because I have a large csv file and it is separate in two columns - first the modul and second the modul item. Therefore Im creating a tuple, because it is the best way to define a modul and the modul items. That is the best well known to me way, but I don't know so much in programming, you know. It doesn't matter that tuples are immutable. I don't need to change it later.

Comment: Im tyring to loop a single integer as a value, because it is the easiest way to create a tuple out of my large csv file. If I use a string as value it will be pretty hard to program the comparison, because commas and brackets will be checked, as well. Any other ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: I would personally set up a dictionary like this to make it easy on yourself: `dict = {'row1dict':
            {
                'col1name': 'col1val',
                'col2name': 'col2val'
            },
            'row2dict':
            {
                'col1name': 'col1val',
                'col2name': 'col2val'
            }
            # ...
        }`