# Why does looping through dict-value tuples using `enumerate()` throw an error?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, tuples, enumerate

This is a result of my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813692/comparison-of-value-items-in-a-dictionary-and-counting-matches/33813814#33813814).

1. Why do I get a `TypeError` as described below?
2. What's the deal with enumerate?

I thought that

```
for k, v in enumerate(iterable)`
```

was equivalent to:

```
for k in iterable:
    v = iterable[k]
```

Apparently it's not. Or at least, it's not equivalent in all circumstances.

[Python docs say](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

> ```
> ... seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>
> ... list(enumerate(seasons))
>
> [(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
>
> ... list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
>
> [(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
> ```

I would have thought then, that `enumerate({1:(1,0)}` would return `(1, (1,0))`.

It doesn't though, it returns an `enumerate` object:

```
=> print enumerate(['list'])
<enumerate object at 0x204bb80>
```

What's really weird is the **type** of error, and when it's thrown (why do the first two loops go?) when you do things wrong.

### Question 1: why does this error occur?

```
dicModul = {0:(0,1),1:(1,1), 2:(2,3,4,5,6,1,7,2), 
              3:(8,1),4:(9,9), 5:(10,10,5,11,0,12,13), 6:(10,11,9,7)}

for val_outerloop, key_outerloop in enumerate(dicModul):
    for val_innerloop, key_innerloop in enumerate(dicModul):
        print "outerloop {}:{}".format(key_outerloop, val_outerloop)
        print "innerloop {}:{}".format(key_innerloop, val_innerloop)
        for x in val_innerloop:
            print "loops!"
```

Output of the above [code](https://repl.it/B1nq):

```
outerloop 0:0
innerloop 0:0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I can't figure out what an enumerate object is (doesn't seem to be in the python docs), and in any case, based on those docs, what I'm trying to do *shouldn't* it doesn't seem throw an error, especially not the `TypeError` that it's throwing.

Background info is below.

## I know (or thought I knew) the following:

`Enumerate()` allows you to **get both the keys and values of items in your dictionary**, or the iteration number and value if you are looping through a list.

With regard to your issue with **iterating over single items**. [Tuples are weird](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), especially with single items. You need the trailing comma or it's not a tuple, it's an int. Honestly, that strikes me as a bug, not a feature, but optimistically, it's probably important for some computer-sciency reason that's way beyond my paygrade. Also, the big thing that distinguishes lists `[]` and tuples `()` is that tuples are immutable. You probably don't need to be using tuples in this case:

```
loopy = (1,)
for x in loopy:
    print x # this will _not_ raise an error

loopy = (1)
for x in loopy:
    print x # this _will_ raise an error

loopy = [1]
for x in loopy:
    print x # this will _not_ raise an error

loopy = 1
for x in loopy:
    print x # this _will_ raise an error
```

Here are two sets of code:

### Codeset 1

```
dicModul = {0:(0,1),1:(1,1), 2:(2,3,4,5,6,1,7,2), 
          3:(8,1),4:(9,9), 5:(10,10,5,11,0,12,13), 6:(10,11,9,7)}

for val_outerloop, key_outerloop in enumerate(dicModul):
    for val_innerloop, key_innerloop in enumerate(dicModul):
        print "outerloop {}:{}".format(key_outerloop, val_outerloop)
        print "innerloop {}:{}".format(key_innerloop, val_innerloop)
```

which outputs:

```
outerloop 0:0
innerloop 0:0
outerloop 0:0
innerloop 1:1
... (you get the idea) ...
innerloop 3:3
outerloop 6:6
innerloop 4:4
outerloop 6:6
innerloop 5:5
outerloop 6:6
innerloop 6:6
```

### Codeset 2

```
for key_outerloop in dicModul:
    for key_innerloop in dicModul:
        val_outerloop = dicModul[key_outerloop]
        val_innerloop = dicModul[key_innerloop]
        print "outerloop {}:{}".format(key_outerloop, val_outerloop)
        print "innerloop {}:{}".format(key_innerloop, val_innerloop)
```

which outputs (more what I would expect):

```
outerloop 0:(0, 1)
innerloop 0:(0, 1)
outerloop 0:(0, 1)
innerloop 1:(1, 1)
outerloop 0:(0, 1)
innerloop 2:(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 2)
outerloop 0:(0, 1)
innerloop 3:(8, 1)
... (you get the idea) ...
outerloop 6:(10, 11, 9, 7)
innerloop 5:(10, 10, 5, 11, 0, 12, 13)
outerloop 6:(10, 11, 9, 7)
innerloop 6:(10, 11, 9, 7)
```

Comment: You need to iterate over a dictionary using one of its methods to return what you want: `keys()`, `values()` or a tuple with both (`items()`). This is true whether or not you are using `enumerate()`.

Comment: `for k in iterable: v = iterable[k]` Nope. `k` is the actual elements in `iterable`, not their indices.

Comment: Note that enumerate returns index,val and not val,index as shown in the example code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few misunderstandings here.

`enumerate` will give you a counting variable, not the key of the dictionary:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i, entry in enumerate(l):
    print(i, l)
```

will result in

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

When you iterate over a dictionary, you are just iterating over the `keys`:

```
d = {'a': (2, 3), 'b': (3, 4), 'c': (5, 5)}
for key in d:
    print(key)
```

will result in

```
a
b
c
```

If you want to iterate over both keys and values use `d.items()` (python3) or `d.iteritems()` (python2):

```
d = {'a': (2, 3), 'b': (3, 4), 'c': (5, 5)}
for key, val in d.items():
    print(key, val)
```

will result in

```
a (2, 3)
b (3, 4) 
c (5, 5)
```

You can combine this like this:

```
for i, (key, val) in enumerate(d.items()):
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for k, v in enumerate(iterable)`
```

is equivalent to

```
for k in range(len(iterable)):
    v = iterable[k]
```

But if `iterable` is a dict, then your iterable is just the keys. If you want the key-value pairs, you can call `dict.items()`

Comment: Thanks for the input! That's incorrect if the iterable is a dict. Also doesn't answer Question 1.

Answer (score 1):

An enumerate object is an iterable, that yields values as necessary.

Note:

```
> print enumerate(['list'])
<enumerate object at 0x204bb80>
> print list(enumerate(['list']))
[(0, 'list')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the primary misunderstanding here is that `enumerate` cares not whether your iterable can be indexed (like `a[0]` or `b['cat']`).

The `enumerate` function just loops and counts. It's the looping, not the indexing that `enumerate` cares about.

#### Looping with a dictionary

Looping over a dictionary will loop over the keys:

```
animals = {'dog': ('betsy', 'miller'), 'cat': ('james', 'mary')}
for item in animals:
    print(item)
```

This returns:

```
cat
dog
```

#### enumerate

`enumerate` will enumerate over an iterable and return a new iterable with indices added for each item in the original iterable.

So using `enumerate` on just a dictionary, we'd expect to see indices and dictionary keys (note that they are unsorted and therefore in an unpredictable order):

```
animals = {'dog': ('betsy', 'miller'), 'cat': ('james', 'mary')}
for item in enumerate(animals):
    print(item)
```

This should give us:

```
(0, 'cat')
(1, 'dog')
```

#### items method

The `items` method will give you key-value pairs for each item in a dictionary.

```
animals = {'dog': ('betsy', 'miller'), 'cat': ('james', 'mary')}
for key, value in animals.items():
    print("key: {}".format(key))
    print("value: {}".format(value))
```

This returns:

```
key: cat
value: ('james', 'mary')
key: dog
value: ('betsy', 'miller')
```